# Proving the Gaussian Integers are a Principal Ideal Domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, principal-ideal-domains, euclidean-algorithm

Is there a good way to show that the Gaussian integers are a Principal Ideal Domain without using the fact that they are a Euclidean Domain? It seems like a lot of extra structure to need to prove along the way.

Comment: It's the usual way to prove the integers are a PID, too, so I don't know that I'd expect anything different for the Gaussians.

Comment: You could instead compute the class number using the usual techniques, but that seems like more work to me.